# Disabling Ctrl-Z behaviour in `ifstream::getline`

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline, webassembly

I want to use `ifstream::getline` to read lines from a file, but the file contains the byte Ctrl-Z (0x1A), which makes `getline` think that it's reached the end of file (this is in Windows -- in *nix it would be Ctrl-D, if I'm not wrong). Can I disable this behaviour somehow, and tell `getline` to ignore Ctrl-Z?

Just for info: the file is `comments.wast` in the [WebAssembly testsuite](https://github.com/WebAssembly/testsuite), which tests the ability of a WebAssembly parser to accept any and all characters inside a block comment.

Comment: I don't think `\x1A` represents Ctrl+Z. Both Ctrl+Z and `\x1A` are interpreted as EOF, but they don't seem to be related?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Ctrl-Z means precisely `\x1A`. (Ctrl-A is `\x01`, Ctrl-B is `\x02` etc.)

Comment: Huh, thanks, didn't know it was a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't happen when your `ifstream` object is using binary mode.
Just create it like this:

```
std::ifstream fin(<path>, std::ios::binary)
```

This of course prevents you from using other features of the stream, but if your main goal is to be able to read all sort of values while ignoring special characters, this is probably the way to go.

Comment: *"prevents you from using other features of the stream"* What features?

Comment: For example, you have to be careful with gcount() and unicode strings...

Comment: I thought that `getline` could only be used on files opened in text mode, but I tried your suggestion and it works just fine.

Comment: Hm, are you saying `ifstream` somehow processes unicode? I thought the text mode merely makes it convert `\r\n` to `\n` (and, apparently, stop at `\x1A`).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat A stream can handle text encodings when a locale is `imbue()`'d into the stream